# How to join three fields from three different tables.MySQL

Tags: mysql

No need for this question as I didn't even end up using it

Comment: You havn't asked a question.  Although the code you've posted is clearly wrong.  If you ask a question about an error, you need to tell people what the error is.

Comment: "three tables" . . . You have four references in the `FROM` to two tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to prefix the columns you're joigning on, in order to avoid ambiguous clauses, and you have to add the `subjects` table to your tables:

```
SELECT students.student_id, entries.exam_date, students.first_name, subjects.subject_name,
FROM students
INNER JOIN entries ON students.student_id = entries.student_id,
INNER JOIN subjects ON students.student_id = subjects.student_id;
```

Comment: In order to help you, you'll have to include the description of your tables.

Comment: @Josh "description" : the fields included in each table. If you have the `CREATE TABLE` queries used to setup your database, add them to your question. If not, try to describe the most precisely your tables.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL will have said something to you along the lines of

```
ERROR 1052 (23000): Column 'student_id' in on clause is ambiguous
```

This is the error message.  When you are stuck on how to fix an error you must always post the error in your question.

As it happens I think the problem is that you have not specified the table in `student_id = student_id` and more than one table has a column called `student_id`.  Also you don't need to join that many times.  You only need to join a table once to use its columns as many times as you like.

So you need code along the lines of:

```
SELECT students.student_id, entries.exam_date, students.first_name,   subjects.subject_name,
FROM students
INNER JOIN entries ON entries.student_id=students.student_id
```

It is as important to learn to ask good questions as it is to learn a programming language.  I recommend reading:  http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html